# Non normality and nonlinearity in a generalized mixed model

Tags: lme4-nlme, normality-assumption, nonlinear

My thesis is about the encroachment in Arctic regions. 
My experiment contained 6 plots, of each type (encroached and non-encroached) on three elevations. Elevation and type are fixed factors, plot is random and is nested in elevation. Which results in the use of a lmer.
I monitored the daily soil temperature during 2 months (July and August). Day is a coninuous covariate. 
My research question is if the temperature difference between both types is getting larger at the end of the growing season, more specific if the soil of the encroached plots are getting warmer than the soil of the non-encroached type.

To test this, I calculated the difference of the soil temperatures (temp_dif) (Non-encroached minus Encroached). The dataset contains 1560 observations and contains some negative values.
My model looks like this:

```
lm1<-lmer(temp_dif~elevation+day+elevation:day+(1+day|eleveation:plot)
```

I tested the normality, and occurring to the Shapiro-Wilk test, it is normally distributed. When I have a look at the qqplot, it seems not to be normal, nor linear.

```
shapiro.test(residuals(lm2))

data:  residuals(lm2)
W = 0.9295, p-value < 2.2e-16

qqplot(day,temp_dif)
```

[image: QQplot, temp_dif and day]

The summary of my model is:(he represents the elevation)

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: tem ~ he + da + he:da + (1 + da | he:plot)

REML criterion at convergence: 4279.1

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.7374 -0.5628 -0.0202  0.4300  6.8245 

Random effects:

 Groups   Name        Variance  Std.Dev. Corr 
 he:plot  (Intercept) 0.7568008 0.86994       
          da          0.0001551 0.01245  -0.89
 Residual             0.8593997 0.92704   

Number of obs: 1560, groups:  he:plot, 12

Fixed effects:    
             Estimate Std. Error t value

(Intercept) -0.150578   0.442680  -0.340    
he2          1.811059   0.626045   2.893    
he3          0.483508   0.626045   0.772    
da           0.013546   0.006593   2.054    
he2:da      -0.027279   0.009324  -2.926    
he3:da      -0.010584   0.009324  -1.135

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
       (Intr) he2    he3    da     he2:da
he2    -0.707     
he3    -0.707  0.500        
da     -0.883  0.624  0.624     
he2:da  0.624 -0.883 -0.442 -0.707  
he3:da  0.624 -0.442 -0.883 -0.707  0.500
```

This is the plot of temp_dif `(plot(temp_dif))`:

[image: Temp_dif_plot]

```
 Summary temp_dif      

 Min.    1st Qu. Median  Mean    3rd Qu. Max. 
-6.3750  0.0000  0.6000  0.6448  1.2000  7.6250
```

So now I don't know how to analyse these data further and I'm a little bit stuck.

Does anybody know how I can resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Can you please add the output of your model's summary as well as the command you used to create this particular QQ-plot? Finally just to clarify what exactly did you test for normality (and what was the exact test output)?

Comment: OK... :) Go ahead and check `?shapiro.test`. Then compare the output you get for `shapiro.test(runif(2000))` vs  `shapiro.test(rnorm(2000))`. I think you will find that you have confused the meaning of this method's output. If anything your results mean you probably do not have data coming from a normal distribution. Anyway this is a minor thing. As mentioned please add to your post the summary output of your model. Consider plotting your `temp_dif` values too.

Comment: And not delete your comments!

Comment: I'm sorry, this new for me :)
I did both shapiro tests, so this means that my data is not normal distributed, right?

Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  rnorm(2000)
W = 0.9994, p-value = 0.84

data:  runif(2000)
W = 0.9523, p-value < 2.2e-16

Comment: No problem; just if you delete comments it seems like someone is talking to himself.  Yes, this means that your residuals are probably not from a normal distribution. Note that you are plotting *deviance* and not *Pearson's* residuals. Based on your later plot is seems like you have heteroskedasticity issues. I think you might have to move to `nlme`'s `lme` so you account for this by using the `weights` (possibly in conjunction with `varPower`).